# Create database from template database, concurrently, in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, testing

In order to run integration tests concurrently, I wish to create a sample database at the beginning of every test. Theses test databases are "clones" of an immutable reference database (the template in `CREATE test_db Template test_reference`).

The cloning (and dropping at the end) operation remains fast enough.

The problem is, I can't clone that reference database concurrently or I get the same kind of error as in the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374726/postgresql-cant-create-database-operationalerror-source-database-template): this is a bottleneck. Is there a way to tell Postgres that I know those concurrent accesses are safe ?

PS: I am not interested for now to change my test setup to the well known strategy which consist in running all my tests in non committing transactions

Comment: I don't think there is a way.

Comment: I don't get that error with concurrent creations (of differently named new databases) using the same template database. I only get that if someone is logged in to the template at the time the creations are occurring, which is not the workflow you describe.  I think you need to provide a minimal reproducible case, as what you have described does not constitute one.

Comment: may I ask how you performed concurrent requests ? I use a connection pool which indeed generates multiple sessions (and I get the error). But If I use a single session, the time to create a database grows linearly (I assume the calls get queued). I can't run the CREATE DATABASE command within a transaction so I wonder how you set up your concurrent queries.

Comment: @jjanes: the way I understand it: the tests are run in parallel. Two (or more) tests want to clone the template database pretty much at the same time. But `create database` will connect to the template database to read from. As long as the `create database` runs, there will be a connection to the template database preventing other CREATE DATABASE statements to use that template.

Comment: Exactly @a_horse_with_no_name. Do you think I need to rephrase my question ?

Comment: I just used bash to create a bunch of psql commands all running at the same time. `for f in \`seq 1 90\`; do psql -c 'create database foobar'$f' template template1;' -c 'drop database foobar'$f & done; time wait`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  But it never actually connects to the template database.  It does copy it, but without formally connecting to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @jjanes in the comments. There is actually no issue: the mistake I made was to use a client connected to the template database to perform the "cloning". If I connect the client to whatever other database, there is no issue and I manage to perform concurrent copies.

PS: however, the performances are not that great either